# Transport selected text from RichTextBox to TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, richtextbox

I'm trying to make a windows form application.

When I select some numbers (by using the mouse) in my richTextBox I need to transport that selected number into my textBox by clicking a button.

What code should I write in this button to make it work properly?

I've tried something like:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
  richTextBox2.Select();
  richTextBox2.SelectedText = textBox1.ToString(); 
}
```

But it doesn't work. Who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Reverse it and add the Text property as the receiving part

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = richTextBox2.SelectedText; 
}
```

No need to call `richTextBox2.Select();`

Answer (score 0):

You're going the wrong direction.  Should just be:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    textBox1.Text = richTextBox2.SelectedText; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        textBox1.Text = richTextBox2.SelectedText;
    }
```